# Simulating conditionals

Tags: c, conditional-statements

How can we code conditional behavior *without* using `if` or `?` (ternary operator) ?

One idea comes to mind:

```
for(;boolean_expression;) {
  // our code
  break;
}
```

Any others ?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @da code monkey - A: curiosity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope what you dont want is just 'if' or 'ternary'.

**#1**

How about this:

Instead of : `if (condition) printf("Hi");`

Use:

```
condition && printf("Hi");
```

**Short circuit evaluation**. This is much similar to using `if` though.

**#2**

For `if (condition) a(); else b();`

Use:

```
int (*p[2])(void) = {b, a};
(p[!!condition])()
```

Using array of function pointers, and double negation.

**#3**

Yet another variant close to ternary operator (function, though)

```
ternary_fn(int cond, int trueVal, int falseVal){
    int arr[2];
    arr[!!cond] = falseVal;
    arr[!cond] = trueVal;
    return arr[0];
}
```

Use it like `ret = ternary_fn(a>b, 5, 3)` instead of `ret = a > b ? 5 : 3;`

Comment: It makes sure that the value is always 0 or 1 otherwise you could have any positive value passed in as true.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(condition){
  case TRUE:
    ourcode(); 
    break;
  default:
    somethingelse();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using function pointers:

```
void ourcode(void){puts("Yes!");}
void somethingelse(void){puts("No!");}

void (*_if[])(void) = { somethingelse,ourcode };

int main(void){
  _if[1==1]();
  _if[1==0]();
  return 0;
}
```

This relies on true boolean expressions evaluating to 1, which happens to be true for gcc, but I don't think it is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: It is guaranteed by the standard that the result of logical operators (`==`, `!=`, `!`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `&&`, and `||`) is either 0 or 1.

Comment: You could have given some better name instead of `_if`.

Comment: @caf: This is true. However, an if() and a ?: both evaluate the "true" path given any non-zero expression, which is worth bearing in mind.  Judicious use of a !! would help here.

Comment: @Regularfry: I didnt intend to compare your method with mine. All I wanted to emphasize was the use of identifier with a leading underscore. I dont remember clearly, but such names are reserved for future implementations in the global namespace. Google it for the relevant section of the standard. :-)

Comment: You're right, identifiers with a leading underscore with file or global scope are reserved. I should have named it if_ :-)